# Cordova project with cordova-plugin-mfp plugin fails with error during runtime

Tags: android, java-native-interface, ibm-mobilefirst

Whenever i use `cordova-plugin-mfp` in my cordova project & try to build with command  `cordova build android --release`, one of the cordova plugin which contains .so file goes down.

But the same project works fine without `cordova-plugin-mfp` plugin.
And the same project works fine with `cordova-plugin-mfp` plugin building with command  `cordova build android`.

I am not able to disclose more about plugin which contains .so file.

Following is the output log:

> A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x0000000c (code=1), thread 2977
>   (WebViewCoreThre)
>
> 04-06 15:17:23.471 10565-10565/? I/DEBUG: signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1
>   (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0000000c

It seems that `GetFieldID` refers to Null at .c file in the plugin.

Comment: Is that your custom plugin and custom .so file? And where is GetFieldID?
 In which plugin?

Comment: Sorry, becouse the plugin is made by other company's library, I cannot tell you the infomation of the plugin. 
GetFieldID is in .c file(JNI) making .so file of the plugin

Comment: GetFieldID is in .c file(JNI) of the .so file this "other" company has provided you?My question is just to know if this 3rd pary .so file contains a GetFieldID within it.

Comment: I'm sorry to have late reply. Yes, GetFieldID is in the company's .c file. We decided to look for another library. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The release mode excludes some files in the project that might seem unimportant. Can you try setting the attribute "minifyEnabled" to false in the "pcportal-build-extras.gradle" file that gets added along with the mfp plugin and run a cordova build android --release ?

Comment: I could not solve it even with your answer. 
It was added together. thank you for your help.

Comment: @lev-guddaguda, what was added together?

Comment: It's cordova-plugin-mfp.